# Optimal method to handle XML received in web method? C# .Net 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml, web-services

What is the optimal approach, from a performance standpoint, when handling XML received as part of web method call? I am composing some web methods that will receive a high volume of calls so I want to be sure I am approaching this aspect of the process in the best way possible.

The amount of XML will be relatively small, basically parameters needed to execute query on DB.

Comment: Any approach is good except when xml is huge.  Any huge xml should be read using XmlReader(). Other xml methods will give out of memory with huge xml.  Xml  has to be read to end before parsing otherwise you will get errors.  So from a performance issue there really is an difference in speed between xml methods.  And memory you have to read entire xml no matter which method is used so there is no way of reducing memory usage.

Comment: XmlReader is good advice.

Also, do you have to read the entire xml? Maybe you don't. In that case, after each read() examine the NodeType, or other properties of the node, provided by the XmlReader, to decide what to do.

About memory usage, I don't agree there is no way of reducing it. Even if you have to read all of the xml, you can read it in chunks if memory is a problem.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.readvaluechunk(v=vs.110).aspx